# Best way for MMS in iphone

Tags: iphone, mms

I am trying to implement an MMS functionality in my app. Because I need
to send text and two images at the same time and I already have an email functionality.
Unfortunately, the current SDK does not allow sending MMS yet. 
What is the easiest and cheapest way to create add an MMS functionality to my app?

Comment: Please do not use signatures in your questions or answers; this is detailed in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to this in the current version of the iPhone SDK.

You will need use your own MMS server and create your own API to talk to that server.